integracion de pyspark con Hive
estoy realizando un trabajo con Hadoop, Hive y Spark, en el cual necesito realizar consultas a tablas que cree en Hive. Estoy intentando conectarme a Hive desde un notebook de jupiter con la biblioteca pyspark de la siguiente manera:
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("laboratorio2").config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083", conf=SparkConf()).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.sql("show databases").show()

Esto es lo que me retorna el show databases:
+------------+
|databaseName|
+------------+
|     default|
+------------+

pero en realidad tengo un database más, esta es la consulta directa en Hive:

No estoy seguro si estoy configurando bien el SparkSession. Igual probe crear la SparkSession sin ninguna configuración, pero tiene el mismo comportamiento. ¿alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo puedo conectarme a las bases de datos que ya tengo creadas? La versión de Spark que estoy utilizando es 2.4.7, y el entorno en el que estoy trabajando es una máquina virtual con ubuntu server instalado.
